# How to produce a map from a stream of the entries?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given `s`, a `Stream<Map.Entry<K,V>>` subject to `s.map(Map.Entry::getKey).distinct().count() == s.count()`, how should I produce `m`, a `Map<K,V>` subject to `m.entrySet().equals(s.collect(Collectors::toSet()))`?

In other words, how should I produce a map from a stream of the entries I want in it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert a stream of map entries to a `Map` by using [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-), passing key supplier and value supplier methods.

```
Map<K, V> m = s.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: So the fact that the stream consists of map entries already is not particularly useful?

Comment: @tennenrishin Correct.

Comment: @tennenrishin, actually methods like `HashMap.putAll(map)` essentially do the similar thing: iterate over supplied map entry set, call `getKey`/`getValue` and put them to itself. The only difference is that they can pre-size the hash-table instead of resizing it several times.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: though nowadays you could do it without dealing with an entry set: `source.forEach(target::put)`.